# Automating ecryptfs mount procedure

Tags: mount, encryption, ecryptfs

I am following below procedure to mount my Private directory

```
root@pc:~# mount -t ecryptfs /testdata/ /testdata/
Passphrase: 
Select cipher: 
 1) aes: blocksize = 16; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 32
 2) blowfish: blocksize = 8; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 56
 3) des3_ede: blocksize = 8; min keysize = 24; max keysize = 24
 4) twofish: blocksize = 16; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 32
 5) cast6: blocksize = 16; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 32
 6) cast5: blocksize = 8; min keysize = 5; max keysize = 16
Selection [aes]: 
Select key bytes: 
 1) 16
 2) 32
 3) 24
Selection [16]: 
Enable plaintext passthrough (y/n) [n]: 
Enable filename encryption (y/n) [n]: y
Filename Encryption Key (FNEK) Signature [b9fc92f854a4c85b]: 
Attempting to mount with the following options:
  ecryptfs_unlink_sigs
  ecryptfs_fnek_sig=b9fc92f854a4c85b
  ecryptfs_key_bytes=16
  ecryptfs_cipher=aes
  ecryptfs_sig=b9fc92f854a4c85b
WARNING: Based on the contents of [/root/.ecryptfs/sig-cache.txt],
it looks like you have never mounted with this key 
before. This could mean that you have typed your 
passphrase wrong.

Would you like to proceed with the mount (yes/no)? : yes
Would you like to append sig [b9fc92f854a4c85b] to
[/root/.ecryptfs/sig-cache.txt] 
in order to avoid this warning in the future (yes/no)? : yes
Successfully appended new sig to user sig cache file
Mounted eCryptfs
```

I want to write a script to automate the whole process. I want to pass the pass phrases, cipher, key bytes etc using a file.

I tried below mount command based on ecryptfs.7 documenetation

```
mount -t ecryptfs -o key=passphrase:passphrase_passwd_file=/home/testpc/key.txt,no_sig_cache,verbose,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=32,ecryptfs_enable_filename=y,ecryptfs_passthrough=n,ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=y secure_folder1/ secure_folder1/
```

where key.txt is

```
root@testpc:/home/testpc# cat key.txt 
passphrase_passwd=1234
```

Once above command is executed ,it asks for FNEK.

```
Filename Encryption Key (FNEK) Signature [13e8b1bc6090e91d]:
```

Is there any way I can pass this through file to automate the whole process ? Once the PC comes up, it should not ask me for any passphrase.

Will ecryptfs-add-passphrase of any help here ?

Thanks in Advance,
Murali Marimekala

Comment: What is the point of an encrypted directory if it is automatically decrypted on boot ?

Comment: Its a special requirement. If this laptop is lost and falls in wrong hands, if they plug hard-drive to another PC, they should not be able to decrypt the data.

Comment: Personally I would just encrypt your home directory and it will decrypt / encrypt with log in / log off. http://bodhizazen.net/Tutorials/Ecryptfs/#Migrate

Comment: Hi Bodhi, thank you. But as per my requirement, I need to encrypt a particular directory. Is there any way to make it encrypted when mounted and unencrypted when unmounted. This needs to be done without asking any passphrase. In a shell script, I tried reading passphrase into a variable used ecryptfs-add-passphrase to get the sig value and passed these values to key and ecryptfs_sig while mounting. Still i get promt asking for passphrase.

Comment: I do not see the point of decrytping without a password but as you wish. You will have to write a script such as expect or wait for someone to script it for you. Encryption is not really designed to decrypt without a password and as I said easiest is to encrypt home.

Comment: It is unhelpful and at best a waste of time to question why the OP needs to do this. There are a million different potential reasons for doing all sorts of things that might have a long backstory, but no reason, however, to explain it in order to seek help. If it cannot be done, then that's the answer. If it can be done, the OP should be helped. Why the OP needs this is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Once above command is executed ,it asks for FNEK.
>
> ```
> Filename Encryption Key (FNEK) Signature [13e8b1bc6090e91d]:
> ```
>
> Is there any way I can pass this through file to automate the whole process ?

You forgot to add `ecryptfs_fnek_sig=` to the options with the FNEK signature you want to use or have used before. I use ecryptfs though mount and it doesn't ask me for FNEK because I have the options set in my command.

Comment: Hi LiveWireBT, thanks a lot for the tip. I used sed to extract sig and assigned to this option. It mounted fine without asking any password. I tried unmounting and mouting back the same directory. Its asking for password (Filename Encryption Key (FNEK) Signature [63e4e3cfbfd842a6]:    )

Comment: My bad, i forgot to pass an argument to my script which was the actual pass phrase. Thats the reason its asking for it. Thanks a lot for your support Bodhi and LiveWireBT.

Answer (score 2):

Implemented below script which solved my problem. Any better suggestions, please let me know.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Argument 1 will be the mountphrase
mountphrase=$1
echo $mountphrase 
echo "passphrase_passwd=${mountphrase}" > /home/testpc/key.txt

#Add tokens into user session keyring
printf "%s" "${mountphrase}" | ecryptfs-add-passphrase - > tmp.txt

#Now get the signature from the output of the above command
sig=`tail -1 tmp.txt | awk '{print $6}' | sed 's/\[//g' | sed 's/\]//g'`
echo $sig
rm -f tmp.txt #Remove temp file

#Now perform the mount
sudo mount -t ecryptfs -o key=passphrase:passphrase_passwd_file=/home/testpc/key.txt,no_sig_cache,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=32,ecryptfs_enable_filename=y,ecryptfs_passthrough=n,ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=y,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=${sig},ecryptfs_sig=${sig},ecryptfs_unlink_sigs /home/testpc/Ecryptfs/secure5 /home/testpc/Ecryptfs/secure5
rm -rf /home/testpc/key.txt
```

Please do review and let me know your comments.